# Trying to upload static video on flask

Tags: html, flask, html5-video, video-processing

I have a video function that processes a video into a .mp4 video using opencv in python and saves it statically in a folder, but I am having trouble trying to upload it to the html when it finishes rendering.

for some reason as well,
I am getting the error below even though video_frame doesn't exist anywhere in my code

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2023 12:09:35] "GET /video_frame HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I have tried to run the video locally on my computer and the video runs as expected. I tried to route it directly through to the html from the files and it still doesn't work with the same 404 error as above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Video Player</h1>
    <video id="video" controls>
        <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vids/vids.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

my directory looks like:

pythonProject1/
static/
vids/
vids.mp4
templates/
video.html
app.py